# Cleanest way for allowing HTML's onClick to access a module's function?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a class:

```js
export default class SubmitModal {
  constructor () {
    this.element = document.createElement('div')
    this.element.classList.add('modal')
    this.element.innerHTML = this.generateContentHTML()
  }

  generateContentHTML () {
    return `
      <div class='modal-content'>
        a bunch of other things
        <button onClick={this.submit()}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    `
  }

  submit () {
     console.log('submitted!')
  }
}
```

What would be the cleanest way for the `button` element to access `this.submit`?

I could make the `submit` function a global by appending it to the `window` variable; however, that seems bad in the long run (if I have two submit functions, etc.).

I also realize that I could simply create a `button` element and add and event listener to it, but is there any way I could do the same utilizing HTML's `onClick`?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the framework you're using.

Comment: @Barmar hey, I know I should be using a framework but that's all vanilla. i'm attempting to make a SPA without one

Comment: `onClick={this.submit()}` looks like it's part of a framework. It's not valid HTML.

Comment: @Barmar yes, my bad, I should put a warning that that is not valid; it's to demonstrate what I want to accomplish. `onClick` works great (example: `onClick={window.alert('test')}`), but it cannot access the `submit` function because it's not in the global variable (`window`)

Comment: Cleanest way, in my opinion, is to use HTML in JavaScript as little as possible. DOM Elements can be created with `document.createElement(tagName)`, assigned to a variable, constructor property, or class property, then acted on more easily without future HTML parsing, which will reduce processing.

Comment: @StackSlave yep, that is true. the only problem is having to create a bunch of `document.createElement()`s, `document.` this and that. i'm thinking about using JSX without React; have you ever heard of or used it? (https://blog.r0b.io/post/using-jsx-without-react/)

Comment: That's not a problem at all. `generateDiv(){ const M = tag=>document.createElement(tag), div = M('div'), btn = M('input'); div.className = 'modal-content'; div.textContent = 'a bunch of other things'; btn.type = 'button'; btn.onclick = function(){ /* do stuff */}; div.appendChild(btn); return div; }` then you `Element.appendChild(SubmitModalInstance.generateDiv())`. You can also do like `this.button = btn;` within that, then you would have the button in other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create it as HTML. Create the button using `document.createElement()`, then use `addEventListener()` to add the class method as the listener.

```js
export default class SubmitModal {
  constructor () {
    this.element = document.createElement('div')
    this.element.classList.add('modal')
    this.element.appendChild(this.generateContent());
  }

  generateContentHTML () {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("modal-content");
    div.innerHTML = `a bunch of other things`;
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = 'Submit';
    button.addEventListener("click", () => this.submit());
    div.appendChild(button);
    return div;
  }

  submit () {
     console.log('submitted!')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it with an arrow function to make it work completely correctly:

```
<button onClick={() => this.submit()}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: That won't work. `onclick` attributes are evaluated in the global scope, they're not closures that capture the local scope.[